# JQuery function in ReactJS for a dynamic viewport height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I got some help in another question on making a table's height equal to the viewport's height. Meaning, if the user resizes the screen, the table height adjusts on-the-fly to occupy the entire height of the screen. My problem now is, this is a React App and I am having a hard time converting this jquery function to React.

My function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function setHeight() {
     windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
     $('.dynamicHeight').css('height', windowHeight + 'px');
   };
   setHeight();

   $(window).resize(function() {
     setHeight();
   });
});
```

Here is a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/jGrbYb) showing the behavior

And here is a screen shot of what I am trying to do
[image]

How can I build this function in React? I'm assuming it will need some modification.

Thanks in advance

NOTE: this may look like another question I made, but it is not a duplicate. It's an entirely different question related to the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the components lifecycle, you should add a componentDidMount method. In that method, simply add a resize handler

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height(),
        }
        this.resize = this.resize.bind(this);
    }
    resize(){
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                width: $(window).width(),
                height: $(window).height()
            }
        });
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So what this does is, when your Component initializes, you set the state to the width and height of the viewport (using jQuery). Then you define a method to update the state, and when your component mounts you attach an resize event listener to it and call the resize method each time the screen resizes. This ensures that your state always contains the width and height of the viewport. Then you can define the width and height of your component by passing that state to your component as props and boom! All good, everytime you resize your screen your component will match it.

If you have any questions let me know. You might need to tinker with this to get it to work (specifically the lifecycle events might not update state as often as you need to) I just whipped it up and did not test it but in theory this is exactly what you need

edit: just a thought, if you want to change the style of your components I would use a style object. So in the child component, do something like this:

```
let style = {
    width: this.props.width + 'px',
    height: this.props.height + 'px'
}
```

And when you render that component

```
<ChildComponent style={style} />
```

Comment: The answer in general makes a lot of sense to me. You're right, I do have to modify it a bit. I am getting some errors without any indication of what exactly is failing. lol

Comment: I wouldn't copy and paste the code above, I'm sure there are some issues but that is the overall gist of what you want to do. Just use that as a template and rebuild it to suit your needs. If you need more help I'm glad to assist

Comment: It's not allowing me to add a constructor inside the const. If I make it a class, that error goes away and accepts the constructor but it doesn't recognize the dollar sign operator

Comment: oh oops it should be class instead of const for sure! lol it's still early over here. Do you have jQuery loaded in to your page? you're still gonna need it to get the screen size (you could try vanilla js screen.height, screen.width but I don't think that will work)

Comment: instead of the $(window).width() try using document.documentElement.clientWidth and document.documentElement.clientHeight. That should work and you won't need jQuery. If that doesn't work try window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth

Comment: Well, well, well, Linter doesn't like the $ operator but my console is clear of errors and the code works. Had to do some other tweaks in the css files but I think it worked. Thanks man. This helped a lot!